# How to exclude rows for the same ID based on Category and Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

```
+--+-------+----------+---+
|ID|OrderID|OrderDate |Cat|
+--+-------+----------+---+
|1 |240904 |23/05/2013|63 |
+--+-------+----------+---+
|1 |338584 |11/12/2013|64 |
+--+-------+----------+---+
|1 |47309  |21/11/2011|64 |
+--+-------+----------+---+
|2 |175307 |23/11/2012|63  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
+--+-------+----------+---+
|2 |195307 |24/12/2012|64  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
+--+-------+----------+---+
|2 |175300 |23/11/2011|63  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
+--+-------+----------+---+
|5 |175307 |23/11/2012|63  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
+--+-------+----------+---+
|5 |215307 |15/1/2013|64  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
+--+-------+----------+---+
|7 |195307 |15/06/2012|63  |
+--+-------+----------+---+
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I trying (struggling) to find a way to get more recent `OrderDate` for `Cat 64` then `Cat 63` for on the same ID all from the table that looks as those records separated by `|` above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mihai :)

Comment: Have you tried my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
Select OrderID,OrderDate From
(
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by ID,CAT Order by OrderDate DESC) AS RN
From tbl
) AS Tmp
Where RN = 1
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88df93/7)

Comment: Thanks Vignesh :) I'm trying it now.

Comment: I'm getting a list of all orderID's for each ID, Vagnesh. What I'd need to get is one orderid that orderdate is larger than than any orderdate on cat 63. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Mention ID = 1 in inner where condition. I have updated my solution

Comment: BIG thanks Vignesh :) I should add that ID's are multiple within that table. Multiple orderdates for each ID and only two categories. Would it makes sense or you prefer me to post a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited my question, dear Vignesh. What I need to get is only the OrderID's for Cat 64 with OrderDate more recent than for any order for Cat 63 providing both cat 63 and 64 sale were made for the same ID

Comment: @ThomasPollack I have updated solution man, Please check with my demo

Comment: Tested. Thanks for your time with this Vignesh! :) 
It returns all the records for Cat 64 based on ID but, it doesn't filter the result. 
Lets assume that one ID has two rows with different orderdate and different cat. What I need to get is one row for that id with orderdate larger for cat 64 than for cat 63. 
Perhaps I'm not building my question correctly :(